# Assigning buttons to input fields

Tags: html, button, enter

Is there a way to assign input fields to buttons in html, so that hitting enter within the input triggers the action called by the button's onclick?

I know it can be done by using the keydown event of the input and calling directly the code in the button's onclick, but isn't there any nicer way? Like stg purely html, like the *for="someId"* attribute of the labels, or at least a one-liner in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always call the `.click()` method in jQuery which will activate the click function of the button. So if there is a button with id `#colorme`, then you could call something like:

```
if(e.keyCode == 13) $('#colorme').click();
```

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2tuk/1/) for the action. Otherwise, AFAIK it isn't a standard HTML thing to do so something like this is your best bet.

You could even probably abstract this into a function which will make it easier to access.